# Why $(document).append() doesn't work in jQuery 1.9.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why following piece of code doesn't work since jQuery 1.9.1? With previous versions works fine.

```
$(function () { 
    $(document).append(test);
    document.write('done');
});
var test = {
    version: "1.0",
};
```

JSFiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/Chessjan/NsjqM/](http://jsfiddle.net/Chessjan/NsjqM)

In JS console it issues error like this:

```
TypeError: document is null
safeFrag = document.createDocumentFragment(); jquery-1.9.1.js (line 5823)
```

Edit:

Thanks everybody for quick and extensive aswers. Observed issue was found by accident, and of course, `$(document.body).append()` is proper approach.

Comment: You normally append stuff to `head` or `body`. Any specific reason for appending stuff to `document`?

Comment: The real mystery is why it should have worked in the first place.

Comment: I am preplexed, can we append to document? because I think, document is not a element (or tag) like `body` or `html` tags.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

jQuery 1.9.x calls

```
this[ 0 ].ownerDocument
```

within its `buildFragment()` method. Since you pass in the `document`, the call

```
document.ownerDocument
```

will reference to `null` and cause the error. Any other node will reference the `document`, which of course, works.

---

Conclusion: Don't call `$(document).append()` but use `$(document.body)` for instance.

Comment: Other answers were also right, but this one exactly explained source of the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your code will of **never** worked. It has to `document.body` **not** `document`.

Here's a few examples in different versions of it not working:

jQuery 1.6.4: http://jsfiddle.net/us9Kz/

jQuery 1.7.2: http://jsfiddle.net/us9Kz/1/

jQuery 1.8.3: http://jsfiddle.net/us9Kz/3/

jQuery 1.9.1: http://jsfiddle.net/us9Kz/4/

jQuery 2.0.0b1: http://jsfiddle.net/us9Kz/5/

Code working with `document.body` (on jQuery 1.9.1): http://jsfiddle.net/us9Kz/6/

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question i tried in JSfiddle all the available jQuery versions. It happened to give the same error.

Why it doesnt work: document becomes something like [object HTMLDocument] when cast to string, and there is of course no such id, it will return null.

The following works:

```
var test = "1.0"
$('body').append(test);
```

or doing it trough object notation like you did:

```
var test = {
    version: '1.0'
}
$('body').append(test.version)
```

Comment: Sure a better approach, but doesn't answer the question either.

Comment: you are right so i editted it somehow to answer the question thanks for your feedback makes me read the question better =) have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Inside the jQuery code it has this line:

```
jQuery.buildFragment( args, this[ 0 ].ownerDocument, false, this );
```

`this` is the jQuery object you selected. In your case, the document. The ownerDocument value of document is null and this is what is passed through as `document` to the call to `document.createDocumentFragment();`. Hence you get the error that `document` is null (Slightly bad naming of variables there as it makes you think the document object itself is somehow null)

As other people have said. Append to the body instead and it will work fine.