# jQuery - Append embed stream

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to append an embed livestream using jQuery's append method doing the following:

```
function whatever() {
    var $insaneLivestream = $('<iframe class="livestream" src="http://www.twitch.tv/gamesdonequick/embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="378" width="620"></iframe><a href="http://www.twitch.tv/gamesdonequick?tt_medium=live_embed&tt_content=text_link" style="padding:2px 0px 4px; display:block; width:345px; font-weight:normal; font-size:10px;text-decoration:underline;"></a><iframe class="chat" src="http://www.twitch.tv/gamesdonequick/chat?popout=" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="600" width="350"></iframe>');
    $(".embedbox").append($insaneLivestream);   
}
```

Althought I thought this was supposed to work, the element seems to be created but not appended to `embedbox` at all. If I explicitly add the embed's DOM to the document it works like a charm.

Edit: also tried

```
$(document).ready(funtion() {
    $(".embedbox").html('<iframe class="livestream" src="http://www.twitch.tv/gamesdonequick/embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="378" width="620"></iframe><a href="http://www.twitch.tv/gamesdonequick?tt_medium=live_embed&tt_content=text_link" style="padding:2px 0px 4px; display:block; width:345px; font-weight:normal; font-size:10px;text-decoration:underline;"></a><iframe class="chat" src="http://www.twitch.tv/gamesdonequick/chat?popout=" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="600" width="350"></iframe>')
});
```

and still doesn't work.

Comment: you dont have enough code here. `<iframe [embed stream DOM element] </iframe>` is not valid HTML. And you set to that to `$livestream`, but then you are appending `$insaneLivestream`.

Comment: The code inside the braces are way too long, therefore I just wanted to make it shorter. Anyways I edited with the whole thing. And yes, livestream was a typo that wasn't in the document. Updated nethertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key seems to be not the change to `html()` instead of `append()`, but just the ready. `whatever()` must have been getting called before the DOM was loaded. Also, were you actually *calling* `whatever()`, or just defining it?

I would venture that this would also work:

```
function whatever() {
    var $insaneLivestream = $('<iframe class="livestream" src="http://www.twitch.tv/gamesdonequick/embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="378" width="620"></iframe><a href="http://www.twitch.tv/gamesdonequick?tt_medium=live_embed&tt_content=text_link" style="padding:2px 0px 4px; display:block; width:345px; font-weight:normal; font-size:10px;text-decoration:underline;"></a><iframe class="chat" src="http://www.twitch.tv/gamesdonequick/chat?popout=" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="600" width="350"></iframe>');
    $(".embedbox").append($insaneLivestream);   
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    whatever();
});
```

Additionally, `$(document).append(//...)` is bad syntax and will error out, see
[Why $(document).append() doesn't work in jQuery 1.9.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221475/why-document-append-doesnt-work-in-jquery-1-9-1)

I've never tried to `append` to `document`, but I didn't know it didn't work, so that was interesting to learn when researching this question.

Comment: This works. Seems like I completely forgot to double-check (pun intended) to only load the iframe after the DOM elements were ready. You are indeed correct my friend, thanks a bunch! As for your question, I was calling it in my HTML script element.

Comment: word! makes sense. glad to help